# Reading NIV bible for AR points

Tags: catholicism, catholic-bible

I am noticing that my child may earn [Accelerated Reader](http://www.arbookfind.com/default.aspx) 
points for reading sections of the Student NIV Bible. We are Catholic. Is it appropriate for my child to read the Student NIV version of the Bible?

Answer (score 1):

The NIV Bible does not contain the Deuterocanonical Books, which for study purposes should do no harm. It also does not contain Catholic material such as Additions to Esther and Daniel, and these differences could cause some confusion. Finally, all translations involve 'interpretation', although a young child is unlikely to notice the occasional subtle differences in interpretation.

In the end, Bibles say the same thing so, subject to the above comments, you could allow your child to participate in this program, with a clear conscience.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Dick, I might suggest that you review the passages your child is reading in the NIV and compare them with the same passages in the version you are using (or that your Pastor or Parish Director of Religious Education recommends). You might also find this an opportunity for quality time with your child by reviewing the passages together.